# Invalid padding error when using decryptBinary

Tags: encryption, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I have a page in my application where users can upload files. When the file has been uploaded I use the `encryptBinary` function to encrypt the file:

```
<cffile file="#getTempDirectory()##uploaded.serverFile#" 
        action="readBinary" 
        variable="binaryFile">
<cfset encrypted = encryptBinary(binaryFile,application.key,"AES")>
```

But when I then try to decrypt the file using `decryptBinary` I get the following error:

> An error occurred while trying to encrypt or decrypt your input
>   string: Invalid padding

The decryption code is (where `readFile` contains the result of the encryption):

```
<cfset decrypted = decryptBinary(readFile,application.key,"AES")>
```

How might I solve this error? Thanks!

Comment: how are you loading the readFile variable?

Comment: Using  `FileRead` (from Amazon S3)

Comment: Could it be that the file's being read as text, rather than as FileReadBinary() ?

Comment: Thanks, that has done the trick!